# Jetpack Compose Error about kaptGenerateStubsDuboxDefaultConfigFastDebugKotlin FAILED java.io.EOFException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to access the jetpack compose to my project. But when I run it after build, it show the following error.

```
Task :App:kaptGenerateStubsDuboxDefaultConfigFastDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3372)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFChar(ObjectInputStream.java:3773)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3670)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3470)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1216)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils.PluginUtilsKt.decodePluginOptions(pluginUtils.kt:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.synthetic.AndroidCommandLineProcessor.processOption(AndroidComponentRegistrar.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParserKt.processCompilerPluginsOptions(PluginCliParser.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.processPluginOptions(PluginCliParser.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.loadPlugins(PluginCliParser.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.PluginCliParser.loadPluginsSafe(PluginCliParser.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.loadPlugins(CLICompiler.kt:179)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

it's my build.gradle

```
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0' 
 
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0'
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.10'
    }
```

My kotlin version is 1.6.21 and gradle plugin version is 4.2.2.
Because of some historical problems, I am hardly to update my gradle plugin to 7.0.0. How to access jetpack compose in my project, no matter what version is available.